# Como diminuir tamanho do TAB em Sublime Text 3

Tags: html5, sublime-text-3, indentação

Edito arquivos HTML com CSS e JS usando Sublime Text 3.
Para reindentar no Sublime Text 3, uso atalho **ctrl+shift+r** quando colo um código de fora. Qual a melhor prática para automatizar a **tecla TAB** diminuindo as tabulações de 4 espaços para 2, por exemplo?

Comment: Dá um find and replace ...

Comment: Replace? Poderia detalhar sua ideia, por favor?. Se a ideia for "colar de novo", temos **ctrl+shift+v** para colar e indentar.

Comment: Coloquei na resposta

Comment: Vi sua resposta @thxmxx quando colei sua configuração recebi esse alerta de erro:  
Error trying to settings: trailing in Packages\User\Preferences-sublime-settings:8:1  
Onde, 8 é o nº da linha e 1 é a posição da **{**  
  
Tentei editar em outras linhas do **Preferences-sublime-settings**, como no início ou no fim do arquivo. Não tive sucesso, mesmo observando o arquivo salvo: **Preferences.sublime-settings**  Então, pesquisei o menu **View**, **Indentation**, **Tab Width:2** e tive o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Para setar o padrão, vá em `Preferences -> Settings - Default/User` e use a seguinte configuração:

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
  "detect_indentation": false
}
```

**Edit:**
Após definir `Preferences -> Settings - Default/User`, selecione todo o texto vá em `Edit -> Line -> Reindent`

Se quiser adicionar um atalho para para esta ação vá em `Preferences → Keybindings` e adicione

```
[
    { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
]
```

Daí é só sellecionar o texto todo e apertar `F12`.